# Have UIView extend to the bottom of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I put a UIScrollView occupies the whole area of my controller's view. Then I added a UIView (yellow color) on UIScrollView:

[image]

In my controller code, I have set the height of my scroll view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.scrollView.contentSize.height = 1000
    }
```

When I run it and scroll up on the screen, I see this:

[image]

How to make the yellow view component's bottom matches the bottom of scroll view?

Answer (score 0):

From the information provided the only guess could be that you **forgot** to add layout constraints.

In case you did add them, please update the question showing your constraints.